# Select video from gallery, cannot find symbol RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE

Tags: android, android-gallery

Select video from gallery

I am trying the following code to get a video from my phone's gallery:

```
Intent mediaChooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
mediaChooser.setType("video/*, images/*");
startActivityForResult(mediaChooser, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

My problem is that I am getting an error saying that it can't resolve the symbol "RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE"  Any thoughts? Possible entry to the manifest file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to define a global variable just after class declaration like this

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
```

Also the above method works for ICS or bigger.

Answer (score 0):

The requestCode just for onActivityResult interface, Just set it.

```
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 5164654;; //or any int numbers
```